# Enabling/disabling asp.net checkboxes through javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Enabling and disabling checkboxes through javascript for example when I check chk1 and then chk2, chk3 and chk4 will be enabled and if I uncheck chk1 then chk2, chk3 and chk4 will be disabled through javascript?

here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('chkTAR').clicked(function(){
        {
        if($('chkTAR :checked').length == 2)

        $('chkOasis, chkPOT').disabled = true;
        else
        $('chkOasis, chkPOT').disabled = false
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

       function oncheckchange(checked) { 
           var chk2 = document.getElementById('chk2'); 
           chk2.disabled = checked;  
       }
   </script>

  <asp:CheckBox OnClick="oncheckchange(this.checked);"  ID="chk1" runat="server" />
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chk2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Note that chk2's ClientIDMode is set to "Static".

Comment: anyway, why i should put clientidmode into static?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
            $('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').click(function () {
                if ($('#checkbox1:checked,#checkbox2:checked').length == 2)
                    $('#checkbox3, #checkbox4').attr('disabled','true');
                else
                    $('#checkbox3, #checkbox4').attr('disabled','');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="c1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="c2" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="c3" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="c4" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where I should put this inside asp or i will create a js?

Comment: you, should write inside the Script in aspx page.

Comment: I sent the complete example, you can change the reference to jquery to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

This might help you [Disabling/Enabling checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118296/jquery-to-disable-checkbox-once-the-selected-item-is-5)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default6.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default6" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">

        function EnableDisableDIV() {

            if ($("#chkShowPersonal").attr("checked")) {

                $("#dvPersonal").show();

            } else {

                $("#dvPersonal").hide();

            }

        }         

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowPersonal" onclick="EnableDisableDIV()" runat="server" Text="Fruits" />
    <div id="dvPersonal" style="display: none">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" Text="Apple" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk2" runat="server" Text="Banana" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk3" runat="server" Text="Orange" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```